# Is "muscular attachment" synonymous to tendon? (when talking about the insertion of glutei medius and minimus to greater trochanter of the femur)

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, terminology, muscles, tendons

I have read the following two terms in an MRI report (both points refer to the insertion of gluteus  medius/minimus to greater trochanter of the femur):

- mild degeneration of the *muscular attachment* of the left gluteus medius
- mild *tendin*osis of the left gluteus minimus

Is *muscular attachment* (to a bone) synonymous to *tendon*? Or does the *muscular attachment* designate the muscle part that attaches to the tendon? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The tendon and muscle attachment are not the same. In your example, both are affected, so they are described separately.

A muscle extends into a tendon and this into an **enthesis** - an actual attachment site where the muscle is attached to the bone ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2100202/)).

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, it means that muscular attachment = tendon + enthesis?

Comment: No, the tendon is not really a part of the muscular attachment.

Comment: so muscular attachment = enthesis?

Comment: Yes, that's it. It also applies for the sites where _ligaments_ are attached to the bone.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Good to know about ligaments.